# How can I change v-icon color by clicking

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to change the color of the icon after clicking on the icon. I try to add style to the .checkbox-off class but it does not work.

`.checkbox-off { fill: #b3b3b3 !important; }`

Here is my code

```
<template>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div
      v-for="channel in channels"
      :key="channel.name"
      @click="onToggleChannel(channel.active, channel.name)"
    >
      <v-btn class="channel-button mr-3 pa-4" tile icon>
        <v-icon v-if="channel.active">{{ channel.icon }}</v-icon>
        <v-icon class="checkbox-off" v-else>{{ channel.icon }}</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is the script part

```
methods: {
onToggleChannel(active, name) {
const nameCapital = name.toUpperCase();
active = !active;

      if (active && this.channelList.indexOf(nameCapital) === -1) {
        this.channelList.push(nameCapital);
      }
    
      if (!active && this.channelList.indexOf(nameCapital) !== -1) {
        this.channelList = this.channelList.filter(
          (item) => item !== nameCapital
        );
      }
    },

},
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vuetify components have `color` prop. So you can simply do it like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div
      v-for="channel in channels"
      :key="channel.name"
      @click="onToggleChannel(channel.active, channel.name)"
    >
      <v-btn class="channel-button mr-3 pa-4" tile icon>
        <v-icon :color="channel.active ? '#fff' : '#b3b3b3'">{{ channel.icon }}</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```